# How to add variables to Bash script in Python subprocess.call

Tags: python, bash, python-2.7, shell

I have some Python 2.7 code which takes input from the user and stores it as variables.

I would like to execute a test.sh Bash script but using the Python variables which I have created.

For example, what I want to accomplish: `./test.sh -a "VARIABLE1" -b "VARIABLE2" -c "VARIABLE3"` The -a, -b, & -c are Bash options and the variables are the code that goes with them.

This is the code I have so far:

```
Name = input("What is your name?")
Age = input("What is your age?")
City = input("What is your city?")

subprocess.call(['sh', './test.sh'])
```

Comment: This does not work, the print output is simply "0".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `shlex`:

test.sh:

```sh
if [[ ${#@} > 0 ]]; then
  while [ "$1" != "" ]; do
    case $1 in
      -u | --user )
        shift
        user="$1"
        ;;
      -a|--age )
        shift
        age="$1"
        ;;
    esac
    shift
  done
fi

echo "$user:$age"
```

test.py:

```py
import subprocess 
import shlex

Name = input("What is your name? ")
Age = input("What is your age? ")

cmd = "bash test.sh -u " + Name + " -a " + Age 
subprocess.call(shlex.split(cmd))
```

```sh
$ python2 test.py 
What is your name? 'vinzz'
What is your age? '25'
vinzz:25
```

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way for this to all be done within the test.py script?

Comment: what you mean by doing all with the test.py ? convert the bash script into python ?

Comment: I want the contents of the Bash script to stay as they are. Just need the py script with the variables to call the Bash script in a specific way. i.e. ./test.sh -a "VARIABLE1" -b "VARIABLE2" -c "VARIABLE3"

Comment: what wrong with that ? `cmd = "bash test.sh -u " + Name + " -a " + Age` it's doing what you want .

Comment: Is there a way to validate the output of the subprocess.call? When I print I just see "0"

Comment: This is another question .. but you can use `res = subprocess.check_output(shlex.split(cmd))` but check for `subprocess.Popen()` instead.